# Add Watermark on Facebook profile image with an APP

Tags: image, facebook, profile, watermark

Could you please help me with the app that you have made to add a watermark to the people that give authorization to it. I have been searching for that app and i have not found anything neither info about the code to get it. Could yo help me please with this or tell me important information to success in my intention.
Thanks and best regards

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, you **can't** alter the profile image itself. You can retrieve it, upload the to *profile album* but you can't **set** a profile picture.